# Generate public and private key and get private key signature

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I want to use `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.54` in order to generate a public and private key with Bouncy castle.

I tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-bouncy-castle but several things are not clear.

How I can generate a public and private key without using CLI. Can I do this using only Java code and after that get the signature? I don't need to have a `.cer` or `.csr` files. I need ot no this in memory.

EDIT: I tried this code:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Assert;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.Base64;

public class CertificateGenerateTestApiTest {

    String data; // complete certificate and metadata. We need to get of when we generate a certificate
    String signature; // signature of the certificate

    @Test
    public void certificateGenerationTest()
    {
        // Generate private and public keys
        KeyPair keyPair = generateCertificate();

        PublicKey publicCertificate = keyPair.getPublic();

        // Problem 1 - think how to populate "data" variable from public certificate
        // Problem 2 - think how to populate "signature" variable from public certificate

        // Get public key as byte[] in order later on to be stored into DB
        byte[] originalPublicCertificate = privateCertificateToByte(publicCertificate);

        // Let's say we received some certificate by some web client, and we want to verify it against our original certificate
        byte[] secondPublicCertificateReceivedByClient = cloneByteArrayData(originalPublicCertificate);

        // Verify certificate
        Assert.isTrue(verifyCertificate(secondPublicCertificateReceivedByClient));
    }

    private KeyPair generateCertificate()
    {
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());

            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

            return keyPair;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean verifyCertificate(byte[] secondPublicCertificateReceivedByClient)
    {
        PublicKey publicKey = getKeyPayload(byteToString(secondPublicCertificateReceivedByClient));
        boolean verified = false;

        try {
            verified = verifySignature(data.getBytes("UTF8"), publicKey,
                    DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(signature));
        } catch (SignatureException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return verified;
    }

    private boolean verifySignature(byte[] data, PublicKey key, byte[] signature)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
        Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA");
        signer.initVerify(key);
        signer.update(data);
        try {
            if (signer.verify(signature)) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private PublicKey getKeyPayload(String certificateString) {
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            ByteArrayInputStream bis =
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            Certificate certificate = null;
            while (bis.available() > 0) {
                certificate = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
            }

            return (certificate == null) ? null : certificate.getPublicKey();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String byteToString(byte[] publicKeyBytes)
    {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKeyBytes);
    }

    private byte[] privateCertificateToByte(PublicKey publicCertificate)
    {
        return publicCertificate.getEncoded();
    }

    /**
     * Clone byte[] data
     */
    private byte[] cloneByteArrayData(byte[] sourceArray)
    {
        int sourceOffset = 0; /* Starting index in the source array */;
        int destinationOffset = 0; // Starting index in the destination array
        byte[] destinationArray = new byte[sourceArray.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++) {
            destinationArray[destinationOffset + i] = sourceArray[sourceOffset + i];
        }

        return destinationArray;
    }
}
```

I get:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input
```

Comment: (1) 1.54 is almost a decade old; the latest release is 1.75 (2) you can generate a keypair using the standard JCA API `KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(algorithm,"BC")` or the Bouncy 'lightweight' API which varies depending on the algorithm which you didn't tell us (3) yes you can do this in Java code (or anything else that compiles to JVM code, e.g. Kotlin); show what you're trying to do and exactly how it doesn't work (compile error? runtime exception -- with stacktrace? wrong output -- what is it and what should it be?

Comment: I tries this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76963370/convert-byte-to-string-readable-text but I can't get the signature. Can you show me how to get the same result using JVM default classes, please?

Comment: That Q (#76963370) is about a _certificate_, and the signature on the certificate, not a keypair. It sounds like what you really want is to generate a certificate, possibly a self-signed certificate although you aren't clear. Your baeldung link uses the `openssl` program to generate key and self-signed cert, or more simply you can just use the `-genkeypair` option of `keytool` -- it actually generates both a keypair and a self-signed cert. But with the standard Java (JCA) classes you can only generate the keypair NOT a cert. Per your link you can do a cert with Bouncy bcprov PLUS bcpkix.

Comment: yes, you're right. I don't need a certificate. Only public and private certificate and signature of the private certificate.

Comment: You're still not making sense. There is no such thing as a private certificate, nor a signature of one. Moreover you can't both need and not need something.

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76983695/get-private-and-public-keys-as-a-string-and-store-then-into-postgresql-db

Comment: Peter, please take some more time to formulate a clear question. Learn the basic difference between the terms "key" and "certificate" and decide what you want. Please do not just mix the terms and confuse everyone, including yourself. Otherwise, nobody can answer your question. It would also help to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898) by explaining **which** basic problem you want to solve, not to focus on **how** you think you should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite chaotic with regard to naming. You cannot magically turn a key into a certificate just by naming it so. You create a key pair and fetch the public key, always calling it a certificate. An apple is not an orange, even if you call it one.

Anyway, you did not post your full stack trace. If you had, it would have been apparent why your program throws this exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:114)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
    at CertificateGenerateTestApiTest.getKeyPayload(CertificateGenerateTestApiTest.java:98)
    at CertificateGenerateTestApiTest.verifyCertificate(CertificateGenerateTestApiTest.java:61)
    at CertificateGenerateTestApiTest.main(CertificateGenerateTestApiTest.java:45)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Empty input
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:110)
    ... 4 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CertificateGenerateTestApiTest.verifyCertificate(CertificateGenerateTestApiTest.java:65)
    at CertificateGenerateTestApiTest.main(CertificateGenerateTestApiTest.java:45)
```

My line numbers are a bit different after pasting your code into my IDE and adjusting a few things to make it run without JUnit, but the basic information stays the same:

You never initialise the `data` field in your class, but are trying to call `data.getBytes("UTF8")`. That cannot work.

There are many other problems in your code, but this one answers your question why this error message occurs.