# Get private and public keys as a String and store then into PostgreSQL DB

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I use this code generate a private and a public certificate:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());

KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

I tried to store the private and public key into DB using direct `toString()` like this `keyPair.getPublic().toString()`, but I get values into DB:

```
RSA Private CRT Key [5e:cf:06:fc:ff:52:cd:16:3a:b4:28:42:dc:c2:5b:9c:e3:fc:a8:c1],[56:66:d1:a4]
             modulus: 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
     public exponent: 10001
```

Which is not correct. What is the proper way to get the certificates as a String and store them in DB?

EDIT: I tried this:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Assert;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.Base64;

public class CertificateGenerateTestApiTest {

    String data; // complete certificate and metadata. We need to get of when we generate a certificate
    String signature; // signature of the certificate

    @Test
    public void certificateGenerationTest()
    {
        // Generate private and public keys
        KeyPair keyPair = generateCertificate();

        PublicKey publicCertificate = keyPair.getPublic();

        // Problem 1 - think how to populate "data" variable from public certificate
        // Problem 2 - think how to populate "signature" variable from public certificate

        // Get public key as byte[] in order later on to be stored into DB
        byte[] originalPublicCertificate = privateCertificateToByte(publicCertificate);

        // Let's say we received some certificate by some web client, and we want to verify it against our original certificate
        byte[] secondPublicCertificateReceivedByClient = cloneByteArrayData(originalPublicCertificate);

        // Verify certificate
        Assert.isTrue(verifyCertificate(secondPublicCertificateReceivedByClient));
    }

    private KeyPair generateCertificate()
    {
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());

            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

            return keyPair;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean verifyCertificate(byte[] secondPublicCertificateReceivedByClient)
    {
        PublicKey publicKey = getKeyPayload(byteToString(secondPublicCertificateReceivedByClient));
        boolean verified = false;

        try {
            verified = verifySignature(data.getBytes("UTF8"), publicKey,
                    DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(signature));
        } catch (SignatureException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return verified;
    }

    private boolean verifySignature(byte[] data, PublicKey key, byte[] signature)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
        Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA");
        signer.initVerify(key);
        signer.update(data);
        try {
            if (signer.verify(signature)) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private PublicKey getKeyPayload(String certificateString) {
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            ByteArrayInputStream bis =
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            Certificate certificate = null;
            while (bis.available() > 0) {
                certificate = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
            }

            return (certificate == null) ? null : certificate.getPublicKey();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String byteToString(byte[] publicKeyBytes)
    {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKeyBytes);
    }

    private byte[] privateCertificateToByte(PublicKey publicCertificate)
    {
        return publicCertificate.getEncoded();
    }

    /**
     * Clone byte[] data
     */
    private byte[] cloneByteArrayData(byte[] sourceArray)
    {
        int sourceOffset = 0; /* Starting index in the source array */;
        int destinationOffset = 0; // Starting index in the destination array
        byte[] destinationArray = new byte[sourceArray.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++) {
            destinationArray[destinationOffset + i] = sourceArray[sourceOffset + i];
        }

        return destinationArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: `KeyPair` is `Serializable` so you could save it that way

Comment: With `keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded()` the public key is returned as DER encoded key in the common X.509/SPKI format (`byte[]`) which can be stored in binary or, if a string is preferred, Base64 encoded.

Comment: Similarly, `keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded()` returns the private key DER encoded in the popular PKCS#8 format (`byte[]`). Note that keys and certificates are not the same thing.

Comment: ok I get `Required type: String, Provided: byte[]` What should be database filed type? Now I use String type. Is it more appropriate to use byte[] filed type?

Comment: As described above `getEncoded()` exports the keys as `byte[]`. You can store these in the DB either raw or you apply a binary-to-text encoding like Base64 and store the data as string. Base64 has an [efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding#Encoding_standards) of 75% (three input bits become 4 output bits), so it increases the amount of data, which is why storing raw data is more efficient (see also e.g. [binary data in database, blob vs compressed base64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8210293/9014097)).

Comment: ok, I will try to do it. After I store the data as `byte[]` How I can convert it back to usable to a valid Private/Public certificate data?

Comment: There are tens of posts on SO about importing a DER encoded private key in PKCS#8 format or a public key in X.509/SPKI format. Search for posts with `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` and `X509EncodedKeySpec`. E.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11410770/9014097).

Comment: I added the code that I tested. Any idea how to fix the issue?

Comment: I added example code that you can run and see what issues I'm facing.

Comment: Guys note in my case I can change only the code for certificate generation. Code for certificate validation is in another lib and I can't change it.

Comment: Have you changed your requirement - you seem to be talking about certificates a lot now?  Also certificate != public key. The former is a wrapper around the latter with a quite a bit of additional information. Even less are they to do with *private* keys

Comment: You are constantly expanding your question, curiously getting more and more confusing. The posted code can't work because you are trying to import a public key as a certificate (probably it's really because you don't understand the difference between certificate and public key). I would suggest that you post a new question regarding the code and describe there in detail what you are actually trying to do, and this question should continue to deal with the original topic (exporting and storing the keys).

Comment: ok, if you can you give me a hand with this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962408/generate-public-and-private-key-and-get-private-key-signature

Comment: It doesn't help much to post the code elsewhere or to issue more bounties. What is missing is a description of what you want to achieve. Question and code are contradictory. `getKeyPayload()` requires a certificate, you provide a public key. If you need a certificate, your approach of using the public key from the key generation is wrong. If you only want to test the export/import of your key, your code is wrong. You have to solve this ambiguity! You should also remove the duplicate (delete the code either here or in the other question).

Comment: @Topaco can you guide me in order to have a valid Public certificate validation for the above code how should be the certificate generated?

Comment: To create a certificate for a public key, you must submit a certificate signing request (CSR) to a certificate authority or generate a self-signed certificate (with the appropriate restrictions). Both are beyond the scope of this question. However, there are tens of posts on SO about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
KeyPair kp = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA").generateKeyPair();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)){
  out.writeObject(kp);
}
String keyPair = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bos.toByteArray());
```

You can now save `keyPair` in your db. This is more convenient as you'd have to separate the pair using `getEncoded` and that would be impractical with one db column. Obviously it would be more space-efficient as a 'binary' column type

A word of caution though: storing private keys in a database opens them to compromise. Secrets should almost never be stored directly - only as hash values that can be compared to human entries. Privileged operators should only be able to *regenerate* secrets, never to *see* them.

Comment: Serializing a Java object in a database is not a good idea. What if deserialization fails with a future version of Java? What if you want to retriveve the data from another app not written in Java? You should just store the results of `getEncoded()`.

Comment: *Anything might* fail for one future reason or another, but feel free to post an example using `getEncoded()` along with a procedure for putting both keys in the same column

Answer (score 1):

If at all you need to store it, it is easy to handle in textual PEM format. Be sure to employ all the best practices while storing sensitive data. Following is a code scribble that returns the key in a PEM format.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, IOException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    System.out.println(getKeyPem(keyPair.getPublic(), "RSA PUBLIC KEY"));
}

private static String getKeyPem(Key key, String type) throws IOException {
    PemObject pemObject = new PemObject(type, key.getEncoded());
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(byteStream));
    pemWriter.writeObject(pemObject);
    pemWriter.close();
    return new String(byteStream.toByteArray());
}
```